# WP Plugins - SEO Smart Links messes with my plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, seo

I have a client who has set up SEO Smart Links plugin with mine. What SEO Smart Links does replace text with links where it sees fit. Problem is it also replaces text inside the < script > tag

SEO Smart Links disabled (good):

```
var fv1='Zi4QkqP1DAg;eUGIaL2OnxA;UKXgdKKRmJQ;Ejld6hhbk90';
    var fv2='youtube;youtube;youtube;youtube';
    var fv3='';
    var fv4='09 02 2011;25 September 1957;26 mei 1957;26 maart 2008';
    var fv5='Nederland 3 vs 1 Oostenrijk alle doelpunten Nederlan 3 vs 1 Oostenrijk 9 feb. 2011 Sneijder 28 Huntelaar 48 Kuyt 70 Arnautovic 84; Nederland vs Oostenrijk 1 1, 25 september 1957; Oostenrijk vs Nederland 3 2, 26 mei 1957; Samenvatting Oostenrijk vs Nederland (26 03 2008) 3 vs 4';
    var width = 600;
        var height =400;
        var flashvars = {
        totalWidth:width,
        totalHeight:height,
        autoplay:"off",
        autoplayNextVideo:"on",
        menuPosition:"down",
        video:fv1,
        types:fv2,
        thumbs:fv3,
        titles:fv4,
        menuDescriptions:fv5,
    };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            scale: "noscale",
            allowFullScreen: "true",
            wmode:"transparent",
            base:'http://www.fctwente.nu/fotos/wp-content/plugins/wp-videogallery/'
        };
```

Enabled (bad):

```
var fv1='Zi4QkqP1DAg;eUGIaL2OnxA;UKXgdKKRmJQ;Ejld6hhbk90';
    var fv2='youtube;youtube;youtube;youtube';
    var fv3='';
    var fv4='09 02 2011;25 September 1957;26 mei 1957;26 maart 2008';
    var fv5='Nederland 3 vs 1 Oostenrijk alle doelpunten Nederlan 3 vs 1 Oostenrijk 9 feb. 2011 Sneijder 28 Huntelaar 48 Kuyt 70 Arnautovic 84; Nederland vs Oostenrijk 1 1, 25 september 1957; Oostenrijk vs Nederland 3 2, 26 mei 1957; Samenvatting Oostenrijk vs Nederland (26 03 2008) 3 vs 4';
    var width = 600;
        var height =400;
        var flashvars = {
        totalWidth:width,
        totalHeight:height,
        autoplay:"off",
        autoplayNextVideo:"on",
        menuPosition:"down",
        video:fv1,
        types:fv2,
        thumbs:fv3,
        titles:fv4,
        menuDescriptions:fv5,
    };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            scale: "noscale",
            allowFullScreen: "true",
            wmode:"transparent",
            base:'http://www.fctwente.nu/fotos/wp-content/plugins/wp-videogallery/'
        };
```

Notice the < a > tags that pop up. Any idea how to stop this ? Like:  can I change the plugin order - make the SEO Smart plugin run first and other plugins run after so that it does not replace the newly added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, fork that "SEO smart" (i would not call it smart, but that's another question) plugin to ignore stuff between `<script></script>` tags.this will be less complicated than changing the plugins hooking order.

Comment: Thanks! So I should set a higher priority right ? Thanks much appreciated!